# YouTrack doesn't show linked commits in VCS Changes tab

Tags: version-control, gitlab, youtrack

I properly set up **YouTrack** & **GitLab** integration and it seems to be **working**. I used this tutorial: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/standalone/Integration-with-Version-Control-Systems.html

But when I mention issue `ID` in commit message

```
$ git commit -m "my message #PROJ-1"
```

after `push`, it doesn't show in YouTrack at VCS Changes tab. I have to add the commit hash manually ([via YouTrack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT74u.png)) and only then it's ok.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have added the repository under the project's VCS settings? If it is not set to monitor your gitlab repository then it won't pick up any commits, even when you include an issue number. Not sure why it works the other way though!

Comment: Yes, I added the repository to project's settings. The problem was that GitLab couldn't access the YouTrack server in our network _(accepted answer)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this integration to work, YouTrack server has to be accessible by GitLab server, because the later notifies the former about commits. Manually adding changes work another way: YouTrack initiates connections to GitLab.

Comment: That was the problem... GitLab server couldn't access the YouTrack.

Comment: How can I test that the connection is not available? Option to "test settings" (when setting integration in the giltab) seems to return success. Does this mean it is connected successfully? Must there be a #-tag in front of the issue name?

Comment: I'm not fully aware of how this works on GitLab side. #-tag is not required.